Model comparison on data with Cauchy distribution
I am interested in determining the dependence of a state's position in density space, n, on magnetic field. With the magnetic field kept fixed, the presence of the state is measured by an increase in electrical resistance as the density, n, is swept.

The state's position is determined by fitting a scaled Cauchy distribution to the peak representing the state at each magnetic field value. A likelihood function is then constructed consisting of the individual Cauchy distributions with their fitted median and gamma values.

where  represents a function of magnetic field which models the peak position's dependence on magnetic field and by maximizing the likelihood, the fit parameters in  are determined.
I want to test three models of the .
The null hypothesis is B independent: 
The first alternative adds a linear term: 
The second alternative has a quadratic term instead of the linear term: 
I would like to get a p-value on the null hypothesis and perhaps later determine, which of the alternative hypotheses fits better if the null hypothesis is rejected. To do that, I looked into likelihood ratio tests and Wilks' theorem which approximates the test statistic  to a chi square distribution

However, I am not sure if the result can be trusted since I only have the peak position at 46 different magnetic field values.
To get the actual distribution I used non-parametric bootstrapping with replacement on the full sample consisting of 46 pairs of peak position and the magnetic field it was taken at, (B, ). This results in an approximately symmetric distribution of the test statistic around the test statistic on the original dataset. That makes sense since I expect some data points to have smaller residuals than others.
To make the bootstrap work I think I would need to run the same measurement multiple times at each magnetic field value. This way I would have a distribution of peak locations at each magnetic field which could be resampled during the bootstrap. Unfortunately, I can't do more measurements, so I am looking for other options.

Welcome to Cross Validated! What has a Cauchy distribution?

If 50 data points would not suffice for the likelihood calculations, then perforce a non-parametric bootstrap would have little theoretical justification.  Your remark about "multiple data points" suggests you ought to describe your data in more detail because that could matter (a lot).

@whuber, I tried to make the data structure used for the bootstrap more clear. If you think some other details would sharpen the question, I am happy to add those as well.
The likelihood calculation is okay, but it is the asymptotic approach of the distribution of the log-likelihood ratio towards a chi square as described by Wilks' theorem, that I am worried about. I wanted to use bootstrap to get the true distribution and compare it to the chi square with one degree of freedom.

I am struggling with this, because it looks like these are not the original data, but are just summaries of the raw data.  You might very well have a great deal more data (and degrees of freedom) than you are representing here.  Doesn't each peak reflect a portion of a spectrum?  If you don't account for having fit the parameters of each peak to data, you will not have any information about the uncertainty of those parameter estimates.

@whuber, the thing I measure is resistance as I change density. I added a picture of a typical dataset which I fit a Cauchy to at each magnetic field value. Since I don't really have a population of data points, I instead use the parameters from the peak fit, to give some estimate of the position and its uncertainty. My assumption is that when the resistance is largest, the state exists in most of the sample I am measuring on, while when I move out on the tail of the peak, only a small portion of the sample hosts the state.

I don't understand what you mean by "don't really have ... data points:" if so, then what are the points in your plot??

@whuber, the data points in the plot are resistance values, so only one measurement was made for each density value. The state is characterized by very high resistance, so to relate the resistance plot to a probability distribution I make the argument that an increase in resistance is proportional to an increase in the portion of the sample where the state is stable. Sample inhomogeneity gives the peak finite width and reduces its height.

I understand the concept of a spectrum or a scan.  I still cannot understand why you do not consider these points to be the data and analyze them directly as triples $(\rho,B,n)$ with a nonlinear regression model $E[n]=f(\rho,B).$  Just as in any regression problem, you don't need multiple measurements per point to analyze them.  I am curious why inhomogeneity would suggest a Lorentzian peak rather than the (more natural) Gaussian peak.  Although it's hard to tell from this plot, this peak looks more like a Lorentzian convolved with a Gaussian or perhaps a pure Gaussian.

@whuber, please excuse my lack of training in statistics and thank you for suggesting the regression method. I think it sounds like it would work, but I am wondering about how I would test my different hypotheses based on the result of a regression model? Scattering from impurities can give the state a finite lifetime. This causes the state to decay exponentially in time. If you Fourier transform the time-dependent state to frequency (energy) space, the lineshape is a Lorentzian.

That's a nice explanation, thank you. But sometimes the real world intervenes.  For example, both x-ray and gamma spectra theoretically have Lorentzian peaks, but x-ray spectra have Gaussian peaks because other factors introduce so much of a Gaussian component that the Gaussian is always a better fit.  Thus, it's usually worth testing whether the prediction from physical theory is an effective model of the data.// Hypotheses can be tested in various ways, such as likelihood ratio tests, simulation, comparisons of AIC, and so on.
